# Python 3 web scraping options

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm new to Python so I'm sorry if this is a newbie question.

I'm trying to build a program involving webscraping and I've noticed that Python 3 seems to have significantly fewer web-scraping modules than the Python 2.x series.

Beautiful Soup, mechanize, and scrapy -- the three modules recommended to me -- all seem to be incompatible.

I'm wondering if anyone on this forum has a good option for webscraping using python 3.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Will

Answer (score 3):

`lxml.html` works on Python 3, and gets you html parsing, at least.

BeautifulSoup 4, which is in the works, should support Python 3 (I've done some work on this).

Comment: The lxml parsing is good an handles invalid HTML almost as well as BeautifulSoup. It is also faster, but harder to install.

Comment: Ubuntu users can simply install the package `python3-lxml`. BeautifulSoup 4 will use lxml (or other parsers), and focus on the methods for accessing the DOM. So it will benefit from lxml's speed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of new to, but I found `BeautifulSoup 4` to be really good and I'm learning and using this one with `requests` and `lxml` modules. requests module is for getting url and lxml (also you can use built in `html.parser` for parsing, but `lxml` is faster I guess) is for parsing.

Simple usage is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'someUrl'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
```

Not simple example how to get the href's from html:

```
links = set()
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        links.add(link)
```

Then you will get the `set` with unique links from your url.

Other example how you can parse the specific parts of html, e.g. if you wish to pars all `<p>` tags that has class of `testClass`:

```
list_of_p = []
for p in soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'testClass'}):
    for item in p:
        list_of_p.append(item)
```

and many more you can do with it as easy as it seems.